# How to Get complete file path using file upload control in asp.net or any other way?

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to get complete file path using file upload control. I want to use them to get all the files from that directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.  If you could it would be a *huge* security hole and a risk to every user everywhere.